# DC.js scatterPlot ordinal axis tick position

Tags: d3.js, scatter-plot, dc.js

How can I position the value points directly above the ticks (or the ticks directly under the points), using DC.js. I could not manage that, DC.js (or D3.js) positions the value points shifted to the left of the ticks, although the X-value is exactly the tick value.

Important: I need this feature for **ordinal X axis** (it works fine for linear X axis)!

[image: wrong data/tick position]

```
var data = [
  {"x":"a","y":1},
  {"x":"b","y":2},
  {"x":"c","y":3}
];
...
dc.scatterPlot("#mychart")
  .dimension(dimension) 
  .group(group) 
  .x(d3.scale.ordinal().domain(data.map(function(v) {return v.x})))
  .xUnits(dc.units.ordinal) 
  .valueAccessor(function(d) {return d.value;});
```

Complete code see jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/bourbert/59Lmt98w/1/

Comment: Thanks for filing an issue. I think this combination of features has simply not been thoroughly tested and debugged. Link to issue: https://github.com/dc-js/dc.js/issues/1135

Answer (score 0):

In dc.js Bubble Chart modify bubbleLocator:

```
var bubbleLocator = function (d) {
return 'translate(' + (bubbleX(d)+20) + ',' + (bubbleY(d)) + ')';
};
```